# Handling status 500 with try and catch

Tags: javascript, error-handling, fetch, try-catch

I can't tell what is the optimal way to handle the status 500 sent by my API. Could you please help me?
In the case below, when my API responds with a status 500, I wish to set an error message in my redux store. When my API sent a successful status code, I wish to "Fetch the user decks" in my store.

**My first attempt** felt logical and dry to me, but it did not work:

```
const createDeck = async () => {
        try {
          const request = await fetch(`${back}/deck/`, options)
          const response = await request.json()
          store.dispatch({ type: FETCH_USER_DECKS })
        } catch (error) {
          store.dispatch({ type: SET_ERROR, message: error })
        }
      }
```

When the API send a 500 status, no exception seems to be thrown and the code in my catch block is ignored.

**My second and third attempt worked as I excepted them too, but they feel convoluted and weird:**

**2nd attempt:**

```
 const createDeck = async () => {
        try {
          const request = await fetch(`${back}/deck/`, options)
          const response = await request.json()
          if (request.status === 201 || request.status === 200) {
            store.dispatch({ type: FETCH_USER_DECKS })
          } else {
          store.dispatch({ type: SET_ERROR, message: error })
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.log('error')
        }
  }
```

This works, but it ignores completely the catch block, making me wonder: what's even the point of try...catch then?

**Third attempt:**

```
  const createDeck = async () => {
    try {
      const request = await fetch(`${back}/deck/`, options)
      const response = await request.json()
      if (request.status === 201 || request.status === 200) {
        store.dispatch({ type: FETCH_USER_DECKS })
      } else {
        throw response
      }
    } catch (error) {
      store.dispatch({ type: SET_ERROR, message: error })
    }
  }
```

This third attempt make use of catch, but it feels weird to manually throw an exception, to be immediately caught by catch.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Take a look at the [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) docs: "The Promise returned from fetch() won’t reject on HTTP error status even if the response is an HTTP 404 or 500". That's why the `catch` block is ignored in case of status 500: the promise resolves and no error is thrown.

Comment: thanks for you reply Ibsn. Yes, I noticed that the status 500 does not throw an exception. My question is then: what is the good practice? should I manually throw an exception when there is a status 500, and write my code in the catch block (attempt 3), or just write a conditional in my try statement (attempt 2), or something else?

Comment: Personally I find both options are ok. Since you're using `fetch()` it would probably make sense to adopt its implementation model and to not consider a 500 response as an exception (attempt 2). But I wouldn't see anything wrong with your third attempt either (axios, for example, would raise an error in that case). Note that `fetch()` response exposes a `ok` property to check whether the request succeeded or not.

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot!
I did not know about request.ok, nor that axios allowed to configure throw of exceptions for the different status.

Comment: (this solves my question btw. Thanks again)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isbn has properly answered this in the comments. I'm  putting it here again for visibility:
"Since you're using fetch() it would probably make sense to adopt its implementation model and to not consider a 500 response as an exception (attempt 2). But I wouldn't see anything wrong with your third attempt either (axios, for example, would raise an error in that case). Note that fetch() response exposes a ok property to check whether the request succeeded or not"